# Data splitting with createDataPartition dynamically choosing the variable to split the data around

Tags: r, shiny, r-caret

I have a method where I want to split my data depending on a variable.

My code looks like this:

```
split_data <- eventReactive(input$split_btn, {
    req(input$variables)
    
    set.seed(123)
    createDataPartition(data()$Survived, p = input$split_percent, list=FALSE)
  })
  
  train_data <- reactive({
    data()[split_data(), ]
  })
  
  test_data <- reactive ({
    data()[-split_data(), ]
  })
```

This works perfectly, I have a slider that chooses the % of the split and updates it whenever I move It.

The problem comes when I try to use a selectInput to choose between my variables instead of just putting "Survived" since I want ppl that use my app to choose it freely.

```
selectInput("variable", "Seleccione la variable target:",
                    choices = names(data())),
```

```
createDataPartition(data()$input$variable, p = input$split_percent, list=FALSE)
```

These don't work and I get this error:

> Warning: Error in createDataPartition: y must have at least 2 data points

I tried using `as.name()` and `.data[[]]` around my input, but it does not work.

There is something I'm missing about using dynamically selected variables in other functions that require it since I had other problems previously

Comment: The problem is `data()$input$variable`. Try `data()[input$variable]`